# Why my image slider only show the first image instead of all 3 images?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make an image slider in my application using the 'react-simple-image-slider
' package. But it only show the first image only..

In my firestore, my imageUrl is stored like this:

[image: firestore]

In the documentation of the package, it shows that the 'images' should be stored in this format:

The website of this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-image-slider

[image: documantation]

Then, in my application, I have fetched the data and store the imageUrl into the 'image' and pass it into 'SimpleImageSlider' to use it.

```
const ProductPage = ({ collection, match }) => {
    const { items } = collection;
    

    const image = [{url: items[match.params.itemId - 1].imageUrl}];

    console.log(image);
    
    return (
        <div className='collection-page'>
        
        <SimpleImageSlider 
            width={500}
            height={500}
            images={image}
            showBullets={true}
            showNavs={true}
        />
        
            <div className='items'>
                {items[match.params.itemId - 1].name}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

However, the application only show the first image in the slider:

[image: slider]

I have console.log(image) and I thought I already store the 3 imageURL into the array, but I have no idea why it only displays the first one? Is it something wrong on the method I store the 'image' and how can I convert it to fit the structure that the documentation need from the data I fetched from database?

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is of format `url: []`, when the docs say each object in the array should be of format `{ url: "" }`. So, ensure your array looks like this:

```
[
    { url: "https://..." },
    { url: "https://..." },
    { url: "https://..." },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as it will assign an object to each item

```js
const ProductPage = ({ collection, match }) => {
    let { items } = collection;
    

    let image = []

    useEffect(()=>{
      items.map(item=>image.push({url: item.imageUrl}))
    },[])
    

    console.log(image);
    
    return (
        <div className='collection-page'>
        
       {image.length && <SimpleImageSlider 
            width={500}
            height={500}
            images={image}
            showBullets={true}
            showNavs={true}
        />
        }
            <div className='items'>
                {items[match.params.itemId - 1].name}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: I have tried it but it still not works... It cannot show the images, just show the '0'... I think it is just the image.length

Comment: Try it now as I've change the `const` to `let`